# list index out of range Django overlapping

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-validation

Hi When I am checking overalapping i am getting list index out of range,
how i can solve that ,

```
 for i in range(count):
        start_value=(self.data.get(f'applicationvalue_set-{i}-start_value', []))
        end_value=(self.data.get(f'applicationvalue_set-{i}-end_value', []))
        if start_value is not None or end_value is not None:
            value1=[]
            value2=[]
            for start in start_value:
                if start not in value1:
                    value1.append(start)
            for end in end_value:
                if end not in value2:
                    value2.append(end)
            a=range(value1[0],value1[-1])

            b=range(value2[0],value2[-1])
            if a in b.exists():
                 raise ValidationError("overlap not allowed")djangp
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the reason for so many lines of code where you can simply solve it with `set()`:

```
 start_value=set(self.data.get(f'applicationvalue_set-{i}-start_value', []))
 end_value= set(self.data.get(f'applicationvalue_set-{i}-end_value', []))
 
 if end_value.intersection(start_value):
     raise ValidationError("overlap not allowed")
```

Here I converting the list into set, as set datatype contains only unique data, and I can run intersection between two sets. More information can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

#### Alternative

You can consider minimum of end_value to be bigger than maximum of start_value:

```
if min(end_value) < max(start_value):
    raise ValidationError("overlap not allowed")
```

### Alternative 2

I am not sure if you should use set it will mess up the sequence of the input from the user (as set remove any duplicates). If its not an issue, then you can use the following code:

```
prev = None

for x in zip(start_value, end_value):
    if prev and x[0] < prev[1]:
        raise ValidationError("...")
    prev = x
```

Here [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) will return a tuple of items combining from start and end value.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and i checked your codeand its not working

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Hi, There  the intersection is not checking overlapping and what evere i give integer value.

Comment: Please see the alternative answer

Comment: with alternative code it is always giving validation error

Comment: Then I am not understanding the logic for the code here

Comment: ok, when start_value =5 , end_value=10 , seconde time if any user give next start_value=6 and end_value=13 , then i am expecting overlapping error. Please forgive me if my explanation is wrong.

Comment: Its okay, please see the alternative 2 answer.

Comment: i am really soory to say it did not worked for me

Comment: Thats unfortunate, but I hope it will guide you in right direction.

Comment: i have on e question to you will this code will gove me all the value of start_value dfrom the form.py (start_value=set(self.data.get(f'applicationvalue_set-{i}-start_value items', [])))